# when i add a annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy ,my project will fail to load applicationcontext

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

when i add a annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy ,my project will fail to load applicationcontext.But if i delete @EnableAspectJAutoProxy, No exception will occur.Of course,if i delete it,AOP does`t work.I use spring3 and junit4 in my app.Here are some code snippets:

my config class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.*" })
public class CenterConfigration
{}
```

my test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CenterConfigration.class)
public class CenterTest
{
@Autowired
private BeanTest beanTest;

@Test
public void test()
{
    System.out.println(beanTest.name);
    System.out.println(beanTest.value);
    System.out.println("--------");
    beanTest.print();
}
```

my aspect code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@Aspect
public class PNNAspectHandler
{
@Around("@annotation(com.judex.annotation.ParamNotNull)")
public Object validatePNN(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable
{
    System.out.println("check begin...");
    Method method = null;
    Object[] method_args = null;
    Object target = null;
    String method_name = null;

    target = proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget();
    method_name = proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    method = getSpecMethodByClassName(target.getClass(), method_name);
    System.out.println(method.getName());
    method_args = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
    boolean validateResult = validateArgs(method_args);
    if (validateResult)
    {
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    } else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("method:" + method_name + "err!");
    }

}

public boolean validateArgs(Object[] method_args)
{
    for (Object object : method_args)
    {
        if (object == null || "".equals(object.toString()))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public Method getSpecMethodByClassName(Class<?> clazz, String method_name)
{
    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods)
    {
        method.setAccessible(true);
        if (method.getName().equals(method_name))
        {
            return method;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

if i add @EnableAspectJAutoProxy,some exception will occur,here are some info about excetion.

```
信息: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3e6fa38a: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,centerConfigration,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,PNNAspectHandler,beanTest,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator]; root of factory hierarchy
十月 26, 2017 5:43:25 下午 org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
严重: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@23986957] to prepare test instance [com.judex.test.CenterTest@23f7d05d]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
```

...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centerConfigration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.aspectj.util.LangUtil.is15VMOrGreater()Z...

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.aspectj.util.LangUtil.is15VMOrGreater()Z
```

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` almost always means you have a version mismatch or missing dependency (in this case, probably the AspectJ RT).

Comment: It 's right. I solved it according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I reconfigured the jar package and i solved it!